# What client tool do you recommend using with a subversion repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn

I come from a RoR background while using GitHub. I am now working on C#/ASP.NET in VS2010. I have a subversion repo set up at a client site waiting to be used. What client tool do you recommend using with subversion? Command Line (which I like), TortoiseSVN, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has served me well for years. If you want Visual Studio integration, use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/downloads)

Comment: Will he need something like SilkSVN underneath his Tortoise? (Heh, sounds like inquiring if the dog needs to have newspapers beneath him)

Comment: @rlb.usa, not necessarily. As per the initial question, there's already a repository set up. SilkSVN us simple a hosting service. For a hosted solution, I prefer http://www.projectlocker.com/; their free service offer more (Trac integration, more users, more storage).

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) is probably the most used.

If you want Visual Studio integration, you could try [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (Open Source) or [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) (commercial, not free).

Disclaimer: I'm not an Subversion expert (I use Mercurial), but I think these are the ones you hear most about.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2.

AnkhSVN for my Visual Studio projects.

TortoiseSVN for items I don't put into Visual Studio such as image files

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise SVN + VisualSVN (free for open source work). Tortoise SVN has come a long way. Its integrated as a shell extension into the file system, so you dont need VisualSVN if you dont need to access SVN from inside VS.

Answer (score 0):

AxoSoft currently has a great integration product for Visual Studio called RocketSVN, that is currently free (I believe it is a beta).  I've been using it for a couple of months now.  Nice thing is it only tracks the items in your solution explorer.  (vs. Tortoise, which I love, which wants to check in everything, e.g. compiled files in your bin folder, test results, etc.)

I've tried AnkhSVN, this is much better IMHO.

http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn

Comment: One of RocketSVN's bullet points on the link is "No more messy svn:ignore patterns".  But, without those svn:ignore patterns it would seem that you are effectively limited to RocketSVN as your only client (since other clients do not have RocketSVN's built-in ignore list).  This seems somewhat limiting.  Is it?